# an influence + supplementary information accompanying a noun..."influence IN the formation of my character..."

Tags: prepositions, supplementation

I read a senence in dictionary

> My profession had an important influence **in** the formation of my character and temperament.

The structure of the noun "influence" is

**influence + supplementary information accompanying a noun**

It seems to me there is a difference between these two sentences.

> ..."influence **in** the formation of my character..."
>
> ..."influence **on** the formation of my character..."

The first one does not describe what thing an influence is on.

It could be **an important influece on something** which is not specific in the formation of my character and temperament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In" doesn't fit the context of "the formation of my character".

You would use "in" or "on" depending on how you would speak about the subject in any other context. For example, you would say a person lives *in* a town, not on it - so if you were speaking about something having an influence in a geographical area you would say "it has an influence *in* [place]". You can't really say something is *in* "the formation of your character".

The correct version of the two phrases you posted would be:

> (it has been an) influence **on** the formation of my character.

Or you could instead say:

> (it has) **influenced** the formation of my character.

Comment: Is it possible that "influence on something which is not mentioned in the formation of my character..."? The usage of "IN" means an aspect or a way of my character...

Comment: @user9418 Yes, it is correct to say that facets of our personality etc are *in* our character. The "influence" isn't a facet of our character, but it could be an influence *on* things that are *in* our character.